# Does port forwarding dmz to a 'dead ip' improve security for my lan?

Tags: ipv4, port-security

Since there are many evil characters on the net scanning ports and ip blocks programmatically, can I misdirect an attempt to break into my system by setting the dmz port to a dead ip address or perhaps a honeypot on my lan?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?   If someone connects to your honeypot, what will you do?  If the answer is nothing, there's not much point.   If they try to connect to a "dead" IP, they will figure that out soon enough.

Comment: More to @RonTrunk's point, I think that if you need to ask the question, you are not prepared to do this correctly. You should probably start with hiring someone to do a security assessment of your network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't configure port forwarding then your NAT box will just drop the packets. If you configure port forwarding or a DMZ forwarding to an unused IP address then incoming packets will trigger ARP lookups on your LAN. Lots of wasted CPU cycles and lots of broadcast traffic on your LAN, and in the end the packets still get dropped...

And if you ask this question you are probably not experienced enough to run a honeypot in a safe way, causing a major weakness in your network. You NEVER run a honeypot inside your real network.

In short: don't